# Why is my map! loop acting weird?

Tags: ruby

I have this code:

```
#test document for my pseudo code

userInput = "go"

arr = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

while userInput != "exit"

  arr.each do |first|

    first.map! do |second|

      if userInput.to_i == second
        first[second] = "X"
      end

      print "|#{second}|"

    end

    print "\n"

  end

  puts "Type quit for exiting game, or a number"
  userInput = gets.chomp
end
```

If I run this and type in a number this happens:

[image: Screenshot]

If I change the map! to map it works, but in the next iteration the saved "X" in the array is gone because map just returns a new array. I want to change the values of the existing values with map! but why it's acting that weird?

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]" and the linked pages. What is your expected output? Remove the image, and copy/paste the text into the question, formatting it appropriately. If/when the link to the image breaks your question will not make much sense. Please provide a more useful title to the question. The effort you put into the question encourages others to help you. Remember, SO isn't a discussion list or like tweeting. You're helping write a reference book.

Comment: Hi, 
I read through the links you provided and from now on I will use this example for future questions. Thx for bringing it up. 
Have a nice day!

Comment: You should also use that information for this question also, since it doesn't do a good job meeting the requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map!` transforms the array by replacing each element with the return value from the block. The return value of a block is (usually) the return value of the last expression evaluated inside the block. In your case, the last expression evaluated inside the block is

```
print "|#{second}|"
```

which returns `nil`. In other words: every element in your array gets replaced with `nil`, because that's what you told `map!` to do.

Comment: Yep I was too fast with my question to SO. It's too late should go to sleep :D
Thank you I will mark your answer as answer

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

The problem is the print statement in the map loop. This returns nil and it's the last return so everything in the array get's set to nil.

I solved it by putting `second` below the print statement like so:

```
first.map! do |second|

      if userInput.to_i == second
        second = "X"
      end

      print "|#{second}|"
      second

    end
```

Comment: A better solution would be to not use `print` in a `map`-type block. Remember, `map`-type blocks are used to modify the value, turning it into another value. Keep what that block does to a minimum and do only that thing, especially when you're using `map!`. If I'm going to output in the block I'll use `each` and figure out a different way to modify my enumerable object. It's all about keeping things straight in our minds as we manipulate things. Also, it doesn't help to add an answer that shows what you did; it's just redundant, unless it was very useful and other answers didn't solve it.